# "The value of a duplicate key rompt the unique constraint « livre_genre_pkey »" Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to update the Set "genres" in the "Livre" Entity from a web client ( Angular )

```
@Data
@Table(name="livres")
@Entity
public class Livre {
    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    private String titre;
    
    private String description;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "livre_genre",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "livre_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")
    )
    private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();
    
    /* Many books have one Author */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "auteur_id")
    private Auteur auteur;
    
    
}
```

this is the http request sent from client :

**http://localhost:2000/livres/update/7**

**And here the error i get : **

```
ERREUR: the value of a duplicate key rompt the unique constraint « livre_genre_pkey »   Détail : the key « (livre_id, genre_id)=(7, 1) » existe déjà.
```

Please someone tell me how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to know as the code for updating the `Set<Genre>` is not visible. From the message, is telling that the entity already is on database. I can guess that probably you are removing the set, and not removing the elements and adding the new ones.

Check if in your code, when you update the set, you are assigning a new hashset with the elements from your frontend. I am guessing that you are assigning the entity set to the data received from the angular.

If it is the case, try:

```
genres.clear();
genres.addAll(genres_from_angular_set);
```

and avoid:

```
genres = genres_from_angular_set;
```

On the second case, you are generating the relations again, and as some relations `genre` already has been stored, you have the unique key restriction.